SD/µSD card pins
I would like to make a µSD card to USB adapter using this chip and this connector but the SD data pins on the chip are SD_D[0-7] whereas on the connector it's 063 and a bunch of PCIe pins. Which pin corresponds to which?

This socket you've identified is designed for UHS-II or SD Express cards... which, based on your question and the controller you've selected is not something you're planning to support.
The following diagram is from the datasheet:

Pins 1-8 are the "normal" (as of today) MicroSD card pins, with the others being no-connect for these cards. You can leave pins 9-17 disconnected, though I'd suggest you select an alternate socket instead.
If you do indeed want to support these faster cards, then you'll need to look for an alternate solution.

But the datasheet of the chip literally says that it supports SDXC, I'm looking all over the internet to understand how to make a simple SDXC to USB converter but I can't find anything, I'm kinda desperate now.

SDXC is not SD Express or UHS-II ... if you're desperate, do you need to make, or can you buy?

Oh... well looks like I haven't understood SD protocols that well after all, thank you. I'd also like to know if there's a way to just have a converter without having a additionnal usb downstream ports? I guess that would imply a lesser cost

I don't need to add the SD feature (I'm building a hub and want to add an SD and a µSD port) actually but I'm stubborn and decided that I will have them

There are indeed controllers without the USB hub... but you're designing a hub? Note, you'll also likely require one controller for each card type (SD and MicroSD), otherwise there will be odd quirks (i.e: one-at-a-time) and possibly signal integrity issues with the design.

How come I have never found any? Do you have any recommandation for this?
Yes, I am using the USB7216C controller for my huband want to redirect the 2.0 ports to an SD and a µSD port and ofc I will use two controller for the conversion

e.g: USB2244 ... though I haven't used it, and product recommendations are technically off-topic.

The FX3S supports USB3 and (multiple ) UHS-I cards, although it's a relatively complicated chip and probably overkill. Might be worth searching a bit more though, it's a decade old part and there are probably better options now.
